# Service Unavaiable - ApplicationPool won't start

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, application-pool

I have a WCF Web Service which is kept under an Application Pool on IIS.

Lately I've been getting "Service Unavaiable" when I'm trying to make calls to this Web Service. The first thing I tried to do was restarting the Application Pool. I did it and after a couple of seconds, it crashed and stopped.

Looking at the Event Viewer, I found these messages, which by the moment couldn't help me to find where the problem is.

> A process serving application pool
>   'X'
>   reported a failure. The process id was
>   '11616'.  The data field contains the
>   error number.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

After getting a couple of these, I got this one:

> Application pool
>   'X'
>   is being automatically disabled due to
>   a series of failures in the
>   process(es) serving that application
>   pool.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

I've already checked permissions and Application Pool configurations but everything seems to be OK.

Have anyone been through this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the identity that the Application Pool is running under.  If you have it configured to run under a domain account, (and this is on an IIS 6.0 server) be sure that the domain account is a member of the local security group "IIS_WPG", for membership in the IIS_WPG group is needed to run the w3wp.exe worker process.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there're multiple possible root causes, but in my case looking at the application event log I saw seemingly unrelated event that happened at the same time:

```
Faulting application name: svchost.exe_wuauserv, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504177
Faulting module name: wuaueng.dll, version: 7.9.9600.17915, time stamp: 0x558b6c14
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000002b694f
Faulting process id: 0x297c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0b52047cfa008
Faulting application path: C:\windows\system32\svchost.exe
Faulting module path: c:\windows\system32\wuaueng.dll
Report Id: 87e1370b-2113-11e5-827d-a0d3c1241fdb
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Here's what helped me. (And this is total black magic, I don't understand why it worked.)
Taken from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/46a7f091-6680-4574-9626-013f9cd4af40/host-process-error-windows-instrumentation-management?forum=itprovistaapps):

> Start / All Programs / Right Click on Command Prompt / Run as
>   Administrator At the command prompt type the following command:
>
> ```
> sc config winmgmt type=  own
> sc config wuaserv type= own
> ```
>
> This will isoloate WMI and Windows Update in their own svchost.exe,
>   this way they won't affect other running services if it crashes again.
>   After further investigation, WMI could also be a victim, since the
>   problem is that OLE probably code uninitialized twice.

The other guy on the thread reported that only the first command worked for him, though the issue went away:

> I followed your directions with the following results.
>
> ```
> Sc config winmgmt type= own
> SUCCESS
> Sc config wuaserv type= own
> [SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:
> The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
> ```
>
> Although one of the commands failed, I am no longer getting the host
>   error message

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things you can try..

1. Try to create a separate App-pool in IIS and use that app-pool in the WCF service. 
   This way, the app-pool is entirely dedicated for the WCF and would not throw any errors.
2. Are you using one of the built-in "Network service" or "Local Service" or "Local System"  for the app-pool identity?  If yes, try to setup a service account and use that in the app-pool identity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are several web services and there's one application pool for each web service. They run using service accounts.